# MS Access complex grouping and sum

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a difficult access question I seem to be stuck on. My data is like the table below, each person has a start and end date and the time in days between the two. What I am trying to do is add together all of the Assignment Lengths that are consecutive, meaning the end date of one is the day before the start date of the next one. In my example below I want to sum the assignment length of records 1,2,3 and separately sum 4,5 because there is a break between the end and start dates. Its in access so I can either do it with a query or with vba, I'm not sure what the best solution here is.
**ID   Name     StartDate    EndDate    AssignmentLength**
1 --   bob --     1/1/2013 --    2/1/2013 --    30
2 --   bob --     2/2/2013 --    3/1/2013 --    30
3 --   bob --     3/2/2013 --    4/1/2013 --    30
4 --   bob --     5/1/2013 --    6/1/2013 --    30
5 --   bob --     6/2/2013 --    7/1/2013 --    30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an additional record to the given data:

```
periodID    fname   startdate   enddate
6           bob     8/1/2013    9/1/2013
```

to have one period that did not span records.  I named the table workperiods.

With the modified data, we can find the work period starts with:

```
SELECT *
FROM workperiods
WHERE periodid NOT IN
    (SELECT a.periodid
     FROM workperiods a
     INNER JOIN workperiods b ON a.startdate =b.enddate+1);
```

We can find the work period ends with

```
SELECT *
FROM workperiods
WHERE periodid NOT IN
    ( SELECT a.periodid
     FROM workperiods a
     INNER JOIN workperiods b ON a.enddate =b.startdate-1);
```

Then we can build this monstrosity:

```
SELECT startdate,
       enddate,
       enddate-startdate AS periodlength
FROM
  (SELECT startdate,
          min(enddate) AS enddate
   FROM
     (SELECT c.startdate,
             f.enddate
      FROM
        (SELECT *
         FROM workperiods
         WHERE periodid NOT IN
             (SELECT a.periodid
              FROM workperiods a
              INNER JOIN workperiods b ON a.startdate =b.enddate+1)) AS c,

        (SELECT *
         FROM workperiods
         WHERE periodid NOT IN
             (SELECT d.periodid
              FROM workperiods d
              INNER JOIN workperiods e ON d.enddate =e.startdate-1)) AS f
      WHERE f.startdate >c.enddate
        OR c.startdate=f.startdate)
   GROUP BY startdate)
```

Which gives:

```
startdate   enddate     periodlength
1/1/2013    4/1/2013    90
5/1/2013    7/1/2013    61
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    31
```

which may be the desired result.

It isn't pretty, but I think it gets there.

Comment: +1 for working through the exercise of coming up with a SQL solution. Sometimes they wind up looking a bit scary, but as a puzzle they're a lot more interesting than firing up VBA and looping through recordsets. ;)

Comment: The end result is exactly what I am looking for, hopefully it works, I will let you know.

Comment: @GordThompson   Thanks for the kind words.  It looked like something that could be done with straight SQL so I wanted to try it.

Comment: Good job. A strait SQL solution is often more desirable than using VBA. I formatted your SQL a bit for readability. +1.

Comment: This worked beautifully, I didn't account for a few things when I posted originally and it took me some time to wrap my head around it to make the changes I needed but ultimately this helped me get to the right solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use VBA and [DateDiff()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx).  Then you could loop through each and compare to see if the total is less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get some ideas from this.  The AssignmentLength could be modified for the actual length of the month.  If you get some ideas please mark as answered.

```
Sub dates()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnStr As String
''Dim below arrays
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
    "C:\Users\Philosophaie\Documents\a  access\a Chase.mdb;"
cn.Open ConnStr
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open Source:="Checking", ActiveConnection:=cn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTableDirect
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
   If rs!Name = "bob" Then
       n=n+1
       datestart(n)=rs!StartDate
       dateend(n)=rs!EndDate
       assignmentlength(n)=rs!AssignmentLength
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
for i=1 to n
    mostart(i)=Left(datestart(i),1)
    dystart(i)=right(left(datestart,3),1)
    yrstart(i)=right(datestart,4)
''do the same for end
next I
for i=1 to n
    if moend(I)=mostart(i) then
        if dyend(I)=daystart(I)+1 then
           if yrend(I)=yrstart(I) then
              aslen(j)=assignmentlength(I)+aslen(j)
           else
              j=j+1
           end if
        else
              j=j+1
        end if
    else
        j=j+1
    end if
  next I
''output
End sub
```